# AWS NEXRAD and pyart grid_from_radars

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3

Can someone take a look at this code and help me debug?

```
import numpy as np 
import pyart


 radar_data=[]
 RADAR_FILE = r'C:\Sourcecode\NEXRAD\KTLX20150506_235157_V06.gz'

 radar = pyart.io.read_nexrad_archive(RADAR_FILE)


 radar.fields['reflectivity']['data'][:, -10:] = np.ma.masked


gatefilter = pyart.filters.GateFilter(radar)
gatefilter.exclude_transition()
gatefilter.exclude_masked('reflectivity')


 grid = pyart.map.grid_from_radars(
(radar,), gatefilters=(gatefilter, ),
grid_shape=(1, 9720, 1832),
grid_limits=((2000, 2000), (-123000.0, 123000.0), (-123000.0, 123000.0)),
fields=['reflectivity'])
```

It fails to make the grid with the error:  "numpy.core._exceptions.MemoryError: Unable to allocate array with shape (9720, 1832) and data type float64"
I think my grid_shape is off somehow...  THanks

Answer (score 0):

Solved.  Installed 32-bit Python by mistake, should be 64-bit for this.